# I'm trying to implement Bootstrap in the code but unfortunately it isn't working. Please help. I can assure there is no mistake of wrong directory

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here I can totally assure you that directory is working just fine but still the problem persists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/css/style.css">
        <title>Helper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Just click below </h1>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Click Here </button>
        <script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here it should have been button success but it's showing simple button.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of your project directory, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely from the bootstrap directory, there is no possible way that there is any other problem, please use a code editor to help you navigate to your directory correctly.

`here is a Code with a cdn bootstrap and its working normally.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Test</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<meta content="" name="keywords">
<meta content="" name="description">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>


<body>
<div class="col-xl-12 text-center">
  <h1>Just click below </h1>
  <button class="btn btn-success">Click Here </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Click Here </button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger">Click Here </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```